# expanding a table so it's grouped by a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have one table that has the follwing columns

```
Team ID    |     Member
1                   2 
1                   4 
1                   1
2                   3 
2                   1
```

How could I return a table that has the first column as the team Id and in the subsequent columns, the members.

Members can be in more than 1 team.

```
1 | member 1 | member 2 |  Null      |  ... 
2 | member 1 |  Null    |  member 3  |  ...
```

Comment: Are teams guaranteed to have a certain number of members? You can't have a table with ragged columns. You literally want to create a new table, not just output the data with one line per team?

Comment: No, the teams can have a different number. And yes to the question about a new table.

Comment: You need to decide on the max number of members per team. What is that number? You probably already know this, but having the members as columns is a less ideal design for a 1..n relationship.

Answer (score 0):

like hatchet suggested if you know the maximum numbers of members per team you can pivot your table for all those values.

am guessing that those are member ids and their names etc are in a separate table, if so you'd have to join on the ids. I'd write out a sample pivot query for you but the data u've given isnt sufficient

Comment: That data is in separate tables. The maximum numbers per team would be 20. I thought that pivot queries were purely for aggregation functions?